# How to build a refresolver to validate REST API response in python?

Tags: javascript, python, json, rest

I am testing REST API of a software via python, which has json schema draft version 4. The software is in NodeJS, and it has a root json to reach sub json through ref in links.

My questions are:

- what kind of mapping should I build to make my work easier. For example:

  I could request for a url, then the url is parsed and mapping to certain schema through reference, then validate.
- Is there any example or description on using `jsonschema.RefResolver` and `jsonschema.Draft4Validator(schema, resolver=resolver).validate(data)` ?  Just couldn't find examples of them.
- Validate through Javascript vs Python jsonschema, which is easier?